# Golang: convert text dump to CSV

Tags: csv, go

I have a txt file dump with data in the following row format:

```
2015/01/01-01:00:00, {'a50': 15.5, 'a95': 14.5, 'a99': 21.5}
```

I'd like to extract the values and turn it into a CSV in the format of:

```
2015/01/01, 15.5, 14.5, 21.5
```

So far I can read the file and extract data, I can also get the timestamp values using a regular expression (but I know regexp in Go are quite slow), I'm avoiding doing more regexp to extract the remaining values. Any pointers?

Comment: "but I know regexp in Go are quite slow" ? [Not true](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).

Comment: "I know regexp in Go are quite slow), I'm avoiding doing more regexp to extract the remaining values" - avoid premature optimisation. 1: it isn't true, and 2: it may be much quicker to write the program using them. It is much easier to speed-up a slow, correct, program than it is to get a program working correctly. So use the easiest path available to get the program working correctly, then worry about speed. Unless your dump files are humungous *and* complex, it is likely using regular expressions will not be the bottleneck; I/O may be *much* slower, and regex will be blazing fast.

Comment: Are all lines of input exactly that format, i.e. is every field the same width, and so the whole line is fixed format, or so some fields vary in width? If it is pretty much fixed, then obviously a regex will work, but maybe a fmt.Fscanf or fmt.Scanf (after reading the line) will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I may follow up to this with a code sample as needed and my time allows but here is a basic rundown of how I would approach the problem.

1) create a type like the one below to hold your data;

```
type line struct {
     A50 float64 `json:"a50"`
     A95 float64 `json:"a95"`
     A99 float64 `json:"a99"`
}
```

2) read the input line by line

3) for each line use `strings.Index` to get the index of the first comma

4) pass the second half of the string into json.Unmarshal by subslicing like;

```
   err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(line[20:]), &MyInstance)
```

5) write the desired output to disk or a buffer using Sprintf like so;

```
  output := fmt.Sprintf("%s, %f, %f, %f\n", line[0:20], MyInstance.A50, MyInstance.A95, MyInstance.A99)
```

EDIT: Noticed a small mistake. You're trimming the time part out of the datetime, you can get that by using `strings.Index` and subslicing again or `strings.Split` on the `-` which separates the two tokens.

One other thing I should point out is I didn't include any file processing code. The way you deal with that depends on your needs. For example, if it were a small amount of data I would probably hold all the output in memory and then write it to disk at the end where as, if the data source is large you'll have to do all this in a streaming fashion (meaning each line is processed independent of the rest).

Comment: Worth pointing out that is that: {'a50': 15.5, 'a95': 14.5, 'a99': 21.5} is invalid JSON, I would need the strings to be enclosed in double quotes, otherwise the json.UnMarshal throws an invalid character error.

Comment: @jwesonga yeah overlooked that. Gotta run a string replace on that substring before passing it into unmarshal.